# filtering out multiple rows based on increasing values by group in data.table

Tags: r, data.table

I have a `data.table` where parents have sons that have been run by batch.
the sum of amounts by batch having the same parent is decreasing.
now my data is bad and I have some cases where it's not the case, in which case i want to just drop all lines having the same "parent_id".

here is an example of such `data.table` with a bad row at line 9:

```
dt <- data.table(
  son_id = c("a1", "a2", "a3", "b4", "b5", "b6", "b7", "c8", "c9", "ck"),
  batch_id = c(1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 2),
  parent_id = c(rep("p1", 3), rep("p2", 4), rep("p3", 3)),
  amount = c(2e6, 1e6, 2e6, 3e6, 3e6, 3e6, 3e6, 3e6, 1e6, 3e6))

dt[,
   sum_amount := sum(amount),
   by = c("parent_id", "batch_id")]
```

we can see that line 9 (ie parent p3, batch_id 2) has a sum_amount of 1e6+3e6 which is bigger than the sum_amount at line 8 ie batch 1 which has 3e6, which is wrong.
Said otherwise:

```
dt[8, sum_amount] > dt[9, sum_amount]
```

So in this use case i would expect to get the same data.table without the parent p3.

I'm open to any solution based on comparison of the sum_amount really...
I tried to do something on the line of:

```
dt[, .SD[, shift(sum_amount, type ="lead") > sum_amount] , by = parent_id]
```

In my example, i see a TRUE at line 8, which has for parent_id "p3" but I'm kind of stuck there...
any idea how either to fix previous line, or even to do it in a more speed efficient way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can select only those parent id's whose `sum_amount` is always decreasing or at the same value. We can use `shift` in this way :

```
library(data.table)
dt[, sum_amount := sum(amount),.(parent_id, batch_id)]

dt[, .SD[all(sum_amount - shift(sum_amount, fill = first(sum_amount)) <= 0)], parent_id]

#   parent_id son_id batch_id amount sum_amount
#1:        p1     a1        1  2e+06      3e+06
#2:        p1     a2        1  1e+06      3e+06
#3:        p1     a3        2  2e+06      2e+06
#4:        p2     b4        1  3e+06      3e+06
#5:        p2     b5        2  3e+06      3e+06
#6:        p2     b6        3  3e+06      3e+06
#7:        p2     b7        4  3e+06      3e+06
```

With `dplyr` :

```
library(dplyr)

dt %>%
  group_by(parent_id, batch_id) %>%
  mutate(sum_amount = sum(amount)) %>%
  group_by(parent_id) %>%
  filter(all(sum_amount - lag(sum_amount, default = first(sum_amount)) <= 0))
```